# tikz and xtable conflict?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pdftex

Hello i'm trying to reproduce this table[image]

this is my code but the "\rowcolors" line is giving me this [image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\title{A title}
\author{Author}
\date{Janvier 2018}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \rowcolors{0}{black}{gray} 
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}

\hline
    \begin{bf}Repository Operations\end{bf} &  \begin{bf} CVS \end{bf} & \begin{bf} Subversion \end{bf} & \begin{bf} git \end{bf} & \begin{bf} mercurial \end{bf} & \hline\\
     atomic commit & yes & yes & yes & yes
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

i used tikz previously to make some diagrams does it have anything to do ? like a conflict between xcolor and tikz ?

could somebody help me pinpoint the reason of this error ? 
thank you by advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this happens usually means that another package loads `xcolor` without the option `table`, in this case `tikz` is doing it. So just load `xcolor` before

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

And that should take care of the conflict.

Down below there are two other problems in your code I corrected

- Change `\hline \\` to `\\ \hline`
- Remove `&` at the end of line
- Change `black` to `white`

This is a working version

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{xspace}

\title{A title}
\author{Author}
\date{Janvier 2018}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \rowcolors{0}{white}{gray} 
  \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \hline
    \begin{bf}Repository Operations\end{bf} &  \begin{bf} CVS \end{bf} & \begin{bf} Subversion \end{bf} & \begin{bf} git \end{bf} & \begin{bf} mercurial \end{bf} \\ \hline
    atomic commit & yes & yes & yes & yes
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]